# Development shell in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, shell, plugins, portability

I write a lot of code, most of it I throw away eventually when I am done with it; recently I was thinking that if I just kept every small piece of utility script I wrote, named it, tagged it and filed it in a dev shell, I will never loose the code, and on top of that I won't need to redo something I have done already, which is the main motivation, as I keep finding myself writing something I've done earlier.

Is there a ASP.NET shell style environment anywhere?

If not, what would be the best way to go about this?

I am looking to be able to do the following:

1. Write big or small bits of code.
2. Derive from or chain together alread written code/libraries/services.
3. Ability to have everything on my desktop (would that mean IIS on the desktop? or is there an lighter weight mechanism?), sync'ed with the server at home, so if I am on the move I can still access this and make this part of my day-to-day workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a unique solution, with many class library projects inside. Each project would address a specific scenario, something like this:

MyStuff (Solution)

- MyStuff.Common
- MyStuff.Validation
- MyStuff.Web
- MyStuff.Encryption

etc.

Then you can put this solution on an online versioning service like bitbucket or assembla, so you can access your source code from anywhere, edit it and commit it back to the server. This way you get the advantages of versioning and you store your code on a remote server so even if your harddisk breaks it's not a problem, cause what's on the server is what matters.

Answer (score 0):

You should either look into a source control system (Git perhaps?) or into a file storage / syncing / sharing service like [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/).
DropBox would allow you to access code snippets from wherever you are and works really easily (just drop a file into a folder).

If you need versioning and branching you're going to have to look into a source control system. Since you have a server at home, that should be no problem.